# Is there a way to test private method which is returning a string that is getting called from a public method and the string is written in file?

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit, mockito

```
private String nameString(String name){
return string;
}

public void fileString(String someName){
File.write(nameString(someName).getBytes(StandartCharsets.UTF_8).StandardOpenOption.CREATE);
}
```

I am trying to write a test method to check whether the name is getting written in the file or not. How do I do that using Mockito?

Comment: `private` methods should not be testsd. Test the public method

Comment: Refactor to get the file system out of the tests, pass an `OutputStream` instead of opening files. Tests then can pass something like a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and real code can pass a `FileOutpiutStream`.